# What should be the time complexity of the following loops?

Tags: loops, time-complexity

Kindly check if the time complexities below are right or not.

**Loop 1**

```
for(int i =0; i*i < n; i+=2)
```

I think that the work done in this loop will be **O(**sqrt(n)**)** because I know that the condition will be met when i reaches sqrt(n). Also, incrementor (i +=2) will cause the result to complete in n/2 so overall work done will be sqrt(n)/2.

**Loop 2**

```
for(int i =0; i*i < n; i*=2)
```

I think that the work done in this loop will be **O(log(n))** because the only thing that changed from previous question is the incrementor (i*=2) which will cause the loop to run in log(n) times. So overall work becomes log(sqrt(n)) which becomes **O(log(n))**

PS: If anyone has a cheat sheet of time complexities of various variants of loops or nested loops, kindly share it. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `O(log(sqrt(n)))` is just `O(log(n))`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the log rules. Thanks, I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you are correct for your assumptions. The time complexity would be O(sqrt(n)). We don't take into account the incrementor +=2 for calculating time complexity since we only take the highest magnitude modificator, in this case i*i < n.

In the second case, you would be right. However, take notice that the loop starts in i=0, and since the increment on this variable is done with i*=2 it will stay at value 0 forever, since 0*2 = 0.

Comment: Thanks. If the loop starts with 1 then the my answer is right or not?

Comment: Yes, it would be. Althought I would modify i * i < n to i * i <= n , so the difference between the starting value of i and the minimum value to break the loop remains the same.